# Handle method in separate class

Tags: xcode, class, methods

in my app I use the same void method very often in different classes. 
I don't want to write the void code in every single class but be able to call it from a separate class because I often have to change code in it and don't want to go through every class and change it separately (minimizing mistakes in code).

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Did you try putting it into a separate class and include it in the other codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class and add the method as a class method to it:

MyHelper.h

```
@interface MyHelper : NSObject

+(void)utilityMethod;

...
```

MyHelper.m

```
@implementation

+(void)utilityMethod {

...
```

Then you can refer to the class:

```
#include "MyHelper.h"

....

[MyHelper utilityMethod];
```

Now the code is in one place and can be added anywhere you want by including the .h file

Comment: Perfect! Works like a charm.

Comment: I use this pattern all the time for anything I want to reuse throughout the app.  It's awesome to have one place to refer to useful bits of code. :)

Comment: Makes me wish Objective C had namespaces.